# If finite group $G$ have non fixed point automorphism $\alpha$ with $\alpha^2 = Id_G$,how the $\alpha$?

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

This problem come from next question:

> If finite group $G$ have non fixed point automorphism $\alpha$ with $\alpha^2 = Id_G$,prove G is a Ablian group with odds order.

There:$a\ne 1\in G$ of group morphism $\alpha$ is a fixed point if $\alpha(a)=a$.

I Think this $\alpha$ is
$$\alpha:G\to G\\
g\to g^{-1}$$
Firstly ,I want to use the non fixed point property .Then ,for any $g\in G$,we conserder
$$\alpha(\alpha(g)g)=g\alpha(g)$$
If $g\alpha(g)=\alpha(g)g$,this problem is closed.But I think it's not clearly to prove $g\alpha(g)=\alpha(g)g$.How can you do?